# Root privileges to install ruby gems on Openshift

Tags: privileges, openshift, root

How can I get root privileges in my Openshift app? I need to install additional gems to my Openshift virtual machine and it's impossible to do it without superuser privileges.

For login, I'm using SSH:
ssh generated-hash@myapp-myns.rhcloud.com

I've already entered my id_key.pub to the Openshift web interface and I'm doing SSH with no password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install additional gems in openshift see [this](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/problems-installing-the-ruby-gem-whois) forum, copied from ramr answer:

> So what you would need to do is add a Gemfile + Gemfile.lock to your
>   app and then do a git push -- see
>   https://github.com/openshift/rails-example for an example
>   Gemfile+Gemfile.lock.
>
> Steps to do that: 1. Create an appropriate Gemfile -- probably
>   something like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'  

gem 'whois'  
gem "minitest"  

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")  
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)  
  puts "Loading Gemfile.local ..." if $DEBUG # `ruby -d` or `bundle -v`  
  instance_eval File.read(local_gemfile)  
end
```

> On your workstation do a bundler install bundle install (you might
>   need to gem install bundler before you can use bundler). That should
>   create a Gemfile.lock - add that and the Gemfile and commit git add
>   Gemfile Gemfile.lock, git commit Gemfile Gemfile.lock -m 'added deps'
>   Push changes to your OpenShift App git push HTH

Comment: It's very nice - the gems are installed in vendor/bundle, but is it possible to load gems from vendor/bundle in a non rails script?