# rails console on openshift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, openshift

I deployed my rails application to openshift it works well but I cannot run 'rails console' on production server. It gives me this error. How can I solve this? I tried to update rubygems but it also gives permission denied error and I couldn't make it too.

rails c error:

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 1.8.24 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:33:in `<module:Spring>'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:77:in `preload'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:140:in `serve'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
from /var/lib/openshift/5429e72a500446dfee000197/app-root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

rubygems-update error:

```
[appname.rhcloud.com repo]\> update_rubygems
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/local/share/ruby
```

Comment: What are the commands you are using? I don't know much about openshift but some quick googling suggests the following cmds

Comment: `cd app-root/repo &&
bundle exec rails console RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: When i use "rails c" command it ignores 'c' and gives a return that as if I write just "rails". when write "bundle exec rails c" it gives the error above. 

and in second part "gem install rubygems-update" works fine and install the gem. but then "update_rubygems" gives the second error.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue, try running it like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

Also make sure you are running it in ~/app-root/repo when you run it

Comment: I tried it, didn't work. But I deployed my app with ruby-2.0 cartridge today, console works. at this time other problems appeared.

Answer (score 2):

To update rubygems:

```
gem update --system
```

If that doesn't solve the problem try Spring's suggestion and run:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Comment: gem update --system worked two commands in one line and at the end gave the same error. 
gem pristine --all gave this
 Restoring gems to pristine condition...
Cached gem for ZenTest-4.8.1 not found, attempting to fetch...
Fetching: ZenTest-4.8.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/share/gems directory.

what is this write permissions how do i get this? people say root access is not needed on paas.

Comment: Then my answer was not helpful, sorry. This is an ownership issue rather than one of execution. are you logged in as admin? The crappy solution is probably to sudo gem update --system, but the correct way would be chown rubygems so you do have permission, but I'm not good enough with bash to walk you through that.

Comment: I guess redhat doesn't allow me to login as root but I am not sure I couldn't find it. nobody say anything about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296732/root-privileges-on-openshift everybody say an another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are multiple bundle executables and the system is using the wrong one.

Locate the correct `bundle` executable. In my case it was located at `~/.gem/bin/bundle`.

If you can't find it, install it `gem install bundler`.

Then run `~/.gem/bin/bundle exec rails console production` inside `~/app-root/repo`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get any of the `gem install` or `bundle exec` solutions to work while running the 4.1.4 Rails cartridge on OpenShift. My solution was running `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails c` in `app-root/repo`.