# Rails console doesn't work (openshift)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openshift

I have been using openshift for a week now, and everything works fine. Unfortunately, neither with Ruby2.0 or Ruby1.9.3 can I access the Rails4 console online, which is a real problem.

```
bundle exec rails console RAILS_ENV="production"
```

fails, asking me to run bundle install, and bundle install fails, telling me it can't install active support 4.1.4, even though during deployment openshift says it is installed in .vendor/bundle. I tried deleted my app several times, recreating, starting with a clean version of the railsapp example on github... nothing works.

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance

```
[app-root/repo]$ bundle exec rails console RAILS_ENV="production"
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
[app-root/repo]$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.6) 
Using i18n (0.6.11) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using minitest (5.4.0) 
Using thread_safe (0.3.4) 
Using tzinfo (1.2.1) 
Installing activesupport (4.1.4) 
Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing activesupport (4.1.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '4.1.4'` succeeds before
bundling.

[app-root/repo]$ gem install activesupport -v '4.1.4'
Fetching: i18n-0.6.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.11
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.4
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: activesupport-4.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.1.4
4 gems installed

[app-root/repo]$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Using rake (0.9.6) 
Using i18n (0.6.11) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Using minitest (5.4.0) 
Using thread_safe (0.3.4) 
Using tzinfo (1.2.1) 
Installing activesupport (4.1.4) 
Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
An error occurred while installing activesupport (4.1.4), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '4.1.4'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I am using the Gemfile provided on Github, with minor changes. I had to modify the following lines a bit, or rails would complain:

```
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring', group: :development
```

had to be replaced by

```
group :development do
  gem 'spring'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end
```

Just ask if you need more info.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
cd ~/app-root/repo && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console
```

And it works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I saw your post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131728/rails-console-on-openshift), that's where I got my inspiration, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Actually, are you using Rails 4.1.4 and Ruby2.0 as well?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift is quite picky with the Gemfile format:

In my case it was:

> gem 'guard-rspec', require: false

Has to be:

> gem 'guard-rspec', :require => false

That fixed the first error, bundle was complaining about the file format, and then I had the problem of the gems not being there.

So again I connected to the console and did a gem install bundler in 
app-deployment/current/repo

and

> ~/.gem/bin/bundle exec rails c

did work this time

Comment: Hi Sergio, I'm not setup up anymore, but that might have done the trick. Thanks!